# PHP: is read file at every page load too heavy?

Tags: php, website-performance

In F3 Framework Controller I wrote a function checking whether MySql data are saved in a file, otherwise loading a form to ask users for that data (similar to Wordpress Installation).

This function is loaded **every time** that a page / method is called:

```
abstract class Controller
{

    /* F3 */
    protected $f3;
    protected $file_configuration = 'setup.cfg';

    function __construct()
    {
        $f3 = Base::instance();
        $this->f3 = $f3;
        $this->setDatabase();
        $this->setup();
    }
}
```

and `setDatabase()` is a simple:

```
private function setDatabase()
    {
        $search = 'TEST';
        $file = $this->file_configuration;
        // Read from file
        $lines = file('app/config/'.$file);
        $found = false;
        foreach($lines as $line)
        {
            // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
            if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
            {
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        if ($found===false)
        {
            $fh = fopen('app/config/'.$file, 'a') or die("can't open file");
            $stringData = "\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            $stringData = "New Stuff 1";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            $stringData = "\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            $stringData = "New Stuff 2";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            fclose($fh);
        }
    }
```

(Please don't see the values of variables... only test at the moment) ;-)

My question is:

Others classes start extending Controller, will I put too much strain on my server reading every time the file?

Can you hint me a best approach?

Imagine wordpress: I think that every time you call the page, it checks if database exists / is properly configured, otherwise stop / ask for insert connection data (username, password, etc)

Answer (score 1):

> Could be (too) heavy for my server performs that check every time?

This is just not good practice in general. If you end up working with other developers and they inherit from Controller as well (which seems like a very centric object in your domain) you will end up with a lot of heavy processing on your server.

**I would suggest only setting things in your constructor that help you create the object. Reading things from the database doesn't seem to be a part of it.**

This will also make testing a pain in the neck for you.

If you really need to do it in the constructor for some reason then I would suggest using the [Singelton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and only create it once. This way you can use its instance without recalling the constructor each and every time.

Comment: Editing the question (imho) has changed my question... Imagine Wordpress: I think that every time you call the page, it checks if database exists / is properly configured, otherwise stop / ask for insert connection data (username, password, etc). I need to perform this. In real scenario, in effect, a CMS is based entirely on a database. So I need to check if it's first installation or no.

Comment: And there are other classes that extends Controller... this is sure, not possibly, but sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

Database servers are really good at caching small frequent queries.  It's opening a database connection that can take some time. However, if most of your requests end up hitting the database for other reasons then you really have not lost anything.

Still, this does seem to be the sort of thing you would store in a session.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is normal, but if you are aware of performance loss, you have to implement some Cache layer between this configuration file and controller.

This simple example looks like (pseudo-code, not sure for correct php)

```php
public function setupConfig() {

    if (is_file('db_config.cache')) {
       $this->setConfig(unserialize(file_get_contents('db_config.cache')));
       return;
    }

    if (is_file('db_config.ini')) {
       $configContent = file_get_contents('db_config.ini');
       if ( null !== ($config = $this->parseConfig($configContent))) {
          $this->setConfig($config);
          file_put_contents('db_config.cache', serialize($config));
          return;
       }
    }

    // ...
    // Ask for config data from user here or set default values or something else

}
```